# DataTables and For Loops

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a DataTable

```
 <table class="tblData" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tal">
            <th class="nw">Email</th>
            <th class="nw">Type</th>
            <th class="nw">Issue Id</th>
            <th class="nw">Credits Remaining</th>
            <th class="nw">Start Date</th>
            <th class="nw">End Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% foreach (var r in Model.GiftVouchers) {  %>
        <tr>
            <td><%: r.Email %></td>
            <td><%: r.SingleIssue == true ? "Single Issue" : (r.CreditExpiry == "Credit" ? "Credit Sub" : "Expiry Sub") %></td>
            <td><%: r.IssueInformation %></td>
            <td><%: r.CreditExpiry == "Credit" ? r.CreditsRemaining.ToString() : "N/A" %></td>
            <td><%: r.StartDate %></td>
            <td><%: r.EndDate %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

This issue i have is that because the for loop is acting upon a single `<tr>` the data table seems to think that there is only one row and displays all the data as a single row so pagination etc isnt working. 
I cant think of a way to get the datatable to know about the for loop and create seperate rows per iteration. Is it possible with datatables to do this? If not what other methods are available bearing in mind that i have potentially 400 plus data entries.

Comment: You should place the closing body bracket  ` </tbody>` under the `<%} %>`.

Comment: Thank you! Can this thread be marked as closed.

Comment: you are welcome. Just wrote it as an answer. You can accept it. So it is would be considered as closed.

Comment: For what it's worth, that's an HTML table.  A DataTable is a class in System.Data (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx).  Getting nomenclature just right makes it easier for your readers to figure out what you are talking about (and increases the likelihood of a fast/correct/good answer.  HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the closing body bracket `</tbody>` under the `<%} %>`.